# We want to attempt to define $\int_{S}^{T}f(t, \omega)dB_{t}(\omega)$ where > $B_{t}(\omega)$ denotes 1-dimensional Brownian motion.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

The following is from [1] and is attempting to define the integral of Brownian motion beginning with simpler functions.

> Suppose that $0 \leq S < T$ and $f(t, \omega)$ is given. We want to
> attempt to define $\int_{S}^{T}f(t, \omega)dB_{t}(\omega)$ where
> $B_{t}(\omega)$ denotes 1-dimensional Brownian motion.
>
> As an initial step suppose $f$ is of the form $\phi(t, \omega) =
> > \sum_{j \geq 0}e_{j}(\omega)\chi_{[j2^-{n}, (j+1)2^{-n}]}(t)$. Then
> define $\int_{S}^{T}\phi(t, \omega)dB_{t}(\omega) = \sum_{j \geq
> > 0}e_{j}(\omega)[B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}}](\omega)$
>
> \begin{equation} t_k=t_k^{(n)} =  \left\{
> >     \begin{array}{lll}
> >         k\cdot2^{-n} & \text{if }\quad S\leq k\cdot2^{-n}\leq T\\
> >         S  &\text{if }\quad k\cdot2^{-n}<S\\
> >         T  &\text{if }\quad k\cdot2^{-n}>T\\
> >     \end{array} \right\} \end{equation}

**Example:**

Choose $\phi_{2}(t, \omega) = \sum_{j \geq 0}B_{{(j+1)}2^{-n}}(\omega)\chi_{[j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}]}(t)$. Then 
$E[\int_{0}^{T}\phi_{2}(t,\omega)dB_{t}(\omega)] = \\ \sum_{j \geq 0}E[B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}})] = \\
\text{How do we get the following} \sum_{j \geq 0}E[(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}})^{2}] = T$

How do we get the final sum and how does it equal $T$ in the example below?

[1] B. Oksendal, *Stochastic Differential Equations*, 5th ed.

Comment: Can you please provide the source material? Also, going forward be sure to use mathjax instead of images.

Comment: @Jessie Link provided.

Comment: Hint: for a BM the increments are -as we know- normally distributed with variance $t_{j+1}-t_{j}\,.$ Now sum this up.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks I can see how we obtain $T$ but how do we obtain $E[B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}B_{t_{j}})] = E[(B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}})^{2}]$. I get $E[B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}B_{t_{j}})] = E[B_{t_{j+1}}^{2} - B_{t_{j+1}}B_{t_{j}}]$

Answer (score 1):

In that piece of text, Oksendal  demonstrates that two different choices of the step function $\phi$ which both look reasonable lead to very different expectations of the stochastic integrals.

- The choice
  $$
  \phi_1(t)=\sum_{j\ge 1}B_{j2^{-n}}\cdot\chi_{\textstyle [j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n-1}\color{red}{)}}(t)
  $$
  (your $\color{red}{]}$ is ***wrong*** here)
  leads to
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb E\Big[\int_0^T\phi_1(t)\,dB_t \Big]&=\sum_{j\ge 1}\mathbb E\Big[B_{t_j}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j}) \Big]\\[2mm]
  &=\sum_{j\ge 1}\mathbb E\big[B_{t_j}\big]\mathbb E\Big[B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j}\Big]\quad\text{(independent increments)}\\
  &=\sum_{j\ge 1}\mathbb E\big[B_{t_j}\big]\cdot 0\quad\text{($N(0,t_{j+1}-t_j)$ distributed increments)}\\
  &=0\,.
  \end{align}
- The choice
  $$
  \phi_2(t)=\sum_{j\ge 1}B_{\color{red}{(j+1)}2^{-n}}\cdot\chi_{\textstyle [j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n-1})}(t)
  $$
  leads to
  \begin{align}
  \mathbb E\Big[\int_0^T\phi_2(t)\,dB_t \Big]&=\sum_{j\ge 1}\mathbb E\Big[B_{t_\color{red}{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j} )\Big]\\
  &=\sum_{j\ge 1}\mathbb E\Big[(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})^2 \Big]=\sum_{j\ge 1}t_{j+1}-t_j=T
  \end{align}
  because for $s<t\,,$
  $$
  \mathbb E[B_t(B_t-B_s)]=\mathbb E[B_t(B_t-B_s)]-\underbrace{\mathbb E[B_s(B_t-B_s)]}_{\textstyle 0}=\mathbb E[(B_t-B_s)^2]\,.
  $$
  (You know why that underbraced term is zero? Hint: remember the independent increments.)

Comment: Typo with the $]$ by me. The expectation in the first example is $0$ due to the independent increments so both $B_{t_{j}}$ and $B_{t_{j+1}}$ have expected value of $0$?  The second part I can now follow thanks!

Comment: @learningmathematics Yes. $0$ due to independent increments.

Comment: As I understand it $B(t) - B(s)$ would be distributed $N(0, t-s)$ for $s<t$. Independent increments means $0 \leq t_{1} < t_{2} \dots < t_{N}$ random variables $X(t_{0}, X(t_{1}) - X(t_{0}), \dots X(t_{N}) - X(t_{N-1})$ are all jointly independent i.e. this kind of relationship $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$? So example 1 get a product of two terms with expected value of$0$. In example 2 the same argument applies to the $B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}}$. Isn't $B_{t_{j+1}} $ distributed $N(0, t_{j+1})$? So we would then have a product of two things with $0$ expected value?

Comment: The point is that in example 2 $B_{t_{j+1}}$ is ***not*** independent of $B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_{j}}\,.$

Comment: I don't understand why. I'm getting myself very confused.

Comment: You wrote in your last comment that $X(t_0)$ and $X(t_1)-X(t_0)$ are independent. $t_0$ is at the ***start*** of the interval $[t_0,t_1]$. Where is $t_{j+1}$ ?

Comment: $t_{j+1}$ evaluates to $\frac{j+1}{2}$ so if we consider the interval $[t_{0}, t_{1}]$ then $t_{j+1} = \frac{t_{1}}{2}$?

Comment: Where is $t_{j+1}$ in the interval $[t_j,t_{j+1}]$? This is the question when you ask if $B_{t_{j+1}}$ and $B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_{j}}\,$ can possibly be independent. Focus  !

Comment: $t_{j+1}$ is the right end point of the interval $[t_{j}, t_{j+1}]$. To determine independence of $B_{t_{j+1}}$ and $B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}}$ I need to compute if $E[(B_{t_{i}} - B_{t_{i-1}})(B_{t_{j}} - B_{t_{j-1}})]=0$ or not (normal random variables independent iff uncorrelated)? I think the issue I am having is I am unsure how I compute that (or is there something more obvious I can do).

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. To probe independence of $B_{t_{j+1}}$ and $B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_{j}}$ you need to compute the expectation of their product and not what you wrote. I guess it is time to take a rest now.